# Calling uniq on a nested joins table

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, uniq

I have three tables, `Show`, `Episode`, and `Character`. Each Show has_many Episodes and Characters.

```
class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :episodes
  has_many :characters

class Episode < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :show

class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :show
```

Episode has the attributes `:air_date` and `:episode_number`. Show has an attribute `:title`.

I have a list of Characters `@characters`. What I want to accomplish is to print a list of the Shows associated with those Characters, ordered by the air date of the Show's second Episode.

```
<% @characters.includes(show: :episodes).where(episodes: {episode_number: 2}).order('episodes.air_date DESC').each do |character| %>
  <%= character.show.title %>
<% end %>
```

This almost works, but **some Shows have multiple characters, so in the printed list, some Shows are listed multiple times.**

Is it possible to apply the ruby method `uniq` to the Shows table in my query, so that each Show is printed a maximum of one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a group by?

```
<% @characters.includes(show: :episodes).where(episodes: {episode_number: 2}).order('episodes.air_date DESC').group_by(&:show).each do |show, characters|
  <%= show.title %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I usually do in your case, is that I look at what I want to accomplish in SQL, write it out, test that it works, then translate it to ActiveRecord or in some cases keep it as a custom SQL query using `find_by_sql`

So here is what you want to accomplish in SQL:

```
Show.find_by_sql(<<-SQL, character_ids_array)
  SELECT
    DISTINCT ON (shows.id) shows.*
  FROM
    characters
  JOIN
    shows on characters.show_id = shows.id
  JOIN
    episodes on shows.id = episodes.show_id
  WHERE
    characters.id IN #{character_ids_array} AND epsiodes.epsiode_number = 2
  ORDER BY
    episodes.air_date DESC
SQL
```

This is unrelated to your main question, but I would suggest doing your logic in the Controller not in ERB. For the sake of convention :)

Also, make sure when you translate to ActiveRecord your query is cashed all the way to the end to avoid N+1 queries.